# Intel compilers fail when math.h is included

Tags: compile, c, icc

I have a very small test `C` program, in a file called `test.c`:

```
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

If I try to compile this using `icc test.c`, I get the following errors, that seem to be complaining about `math.h`:

```
In file included from /usr/include/math.h(420),
                 from     /admin/apps/rhel7/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.196/linux/compiler/include/math.h(95),
             from test.c(1):
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls-helper-functions.h(21): error: identifier "_Float128" is undefined
  __MATHDECL_1 (int, __fpclassify,, (_Mdouble_ __value))
  ^

In file included from /usr/include/math.h(420),
             from /admin/apps/rhel7/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.196/linux/compiler/include/math.h(95),
             from test.c(1):
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls-helper-functions.h(25): error: identifier "_Float128" is undefined
  __MATHDECL_1 (int, __signbit,, (_Mdouble_ __value))
  ^

In file included from /usr/include/math.h(420),
             from /admin/apps/rhel7/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.196/linux/compiler/include/math.h(95),
             from test.c(1):
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls-helper-functions.h(30): error: identifier "_Float128" is undefined
  __MATHDECL_1 (int, __isinf,, (_Mdouble_ __value)) __attribute__ ((__const__));
  ^

In file included from /usr/include/math.h(420),
             from /admin/apps/rhel7/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.196/linux/compiler/include/math.h(95),
             from test.c(1):
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls-helper-functions.h(33): error: identifier "_Float128" is undefined
  __MATHDECL_1 (int, __finite,, (_Mdouble_ __value)) __attribute__ ((__const__));
  ^

In file included from /usr/include/math.h(420),
             from /admin/apps/rhel7/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.196/linux/compiler/include/math.h(95),
             from test.c(1):
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls-helper-functions.h(36): error: identifier "_Float128" is undefined
  __MATHDECL_1 (int, __isnan,, (_Mdouble_ __value)) __attribute__ ((__const__));
  ^

In file included from /usr/include/math.h(420),
             from /admin/apps/rhel7/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.196/linux/compiler/include/math.h(95),
             from test.c(1):
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls-helper-functions.h(39): error: identifier "_Float128" is undefined
  __MATHDECL_1 (int, __iseqsig,, (_Mdouble_ __x, _Mdouble_ __y));
  ^

In file included from /usr/include/math.h(420),
             from /admin/apps/rhel7/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.196/linux/compiler/include/math.h(95),
             from test.c(1):
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls-helper-functions.h(39): error: identifier "_Float128" is undefined
  __MATHDECL_1 (int, __iseqsig,, (_Mdouble_ __x, _Mdouble_ __y));
  ^

In file included from /usr/include/math.h(420),
             from /admin/apps/rhel7/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.196/linux/compiler/include/math.h(95),
             from test.c(1):
/usr/include/bits/mathcalls-helper-functions.h(42): error: identifier "_Float128" is undefined
  __MATHDECL_1 (int, __issignaling,, (_Mdouble_ __value))
  ^

In file included from test.c(1):
/admin/apps/rhel7/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2017.4.196/linux/compiler/include/math.h(1300): error: identifier "_LIB_VERSION_TYPE" is undefined
  _LIBIMF_EXT _LIB_VERSIONIMF_TYPE _LIBIMF_PUBVAR _LIB_VERSIONIMF;
          ^

compilation aborted for test.c (code 2)
```

I'm using `icc (ICC) 17.0.4 20170411`. This was not a problem before, but I'm not sure if the system admins changed the version of the Intel compilers. Either way, something as simple as `math.h` should work, no? How do I make sense of this error?

Comment: You will need to edit your question once you have asked your system administrator what changes they recently made to your system.

Comment: @Ramhound already asked them, waiting for a reply.

Comment: FYI: This question belongs on Stack Overflow not Super User.  [I would try and be specific about which header file you want to use.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5168242/library-include-paths-with-same-header-name)

Comment: @Ramhound okay, I can migrate it there. I figured it was more about the system setup and compilers than the code itself.

Comment: [ICC 17.0.4 + GCC 7 + glibc 2.26: error: identifier "_Float128" is undefined](https://community.intel.com/t5/Intel-C-Compiler/ICC-17-0-4-GCC-7-glibc-2-26-error-identifier-quot-Float128-quot/td-p/1170601) hopefully this helps. According to the forum, adding the compiler flag `-D_Float128=__float128` is a workaround. You can check the forum to see if it's of any help.

Comment: @DrZoo Thanks! That did get rid of all but one errors.